# A picklist automated answer that is dependent on two previous picklists

Tags: custom-object, picklist, dependent-picklist

[image]

Hi all,

Currently trying to build this into salesforce. I need to have a picklist field which is automated on the results of two previous options that are manually selected. They are all on the same object.

Field 1 - Probability: High, Medium, Low

Field 2 - Risk: High, Medium, Low

Field 3 - Automated answer: Minor, Moderate, Critical

Do I need to use visualforce to do this, or can it be done using a validation rule? I have tried using numerous options but can't quite work it out as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula field to get automated answer.

Below formula should work for your case. You need 2 picklist and 1 formula field (Return type Text) for this to work.

```
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Risk__c, 'Low') , 
IF( OR(ISPICKVAL(Probability__c , 'Medium'),ISPICKVAL(Probability__c , 'Low')), 'Minor', 'Moderate') , 
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Risk__c, 'Medium'), 
'Moderate', 
IF( 
ISPICKVAL(Risk__c, 'High'), 
IF( 
OR(ISPICKVAL(Probability__c , 'Medium'),ISPICKVAL(Probability__c , 'High')), 'Critical', 'Moderate'), 
'Moderate')))
```